# Google Sheets Calculate # of times yes is chosen from drop down

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a weekly google sheet with each day of the week as a tab then a tab that calculates weekly totals.  One cell on each daily tab is a yes/no drop down choice.  On the weekly recap tab, I'd like it to pull the # of days that yes was chosen.  Trying to use the COUNTIF formula, but not sure how to select C19 from each tab.

I've tried =countif(Sunday!C19:Saturday!C19,"yes") and =countif("Saturday!C19,Friday!C19,Thursday!C19,Wednesday!C19,Tuesday!C19,Monday!C19,Sunday!C19", "Yes") but neither work.

Comment: I tried using \ such as =countif("Saturday!C19\Friday!C19\Thursday!C19\Wednesday!C19\Tuesday!C19\Monday!C19\Sunday!C19", "Yes") but the final solution that works is using {}!  =countif({Saturday!C19,Friday!C19,Thursday!C19,Wednesday!C19,Tuesday!C19,Monday!C19,Sunday!C19},"Yes")

Comment: Could you please provide a public Google Sheet URL with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're getting an error about the number of arguments being incorrect like:

`Wrong number of arguments to COUNTIF. Expected 2 arguments, but got 8 arguments.`

You need to combine all of the ranges into a single array by using `{}` (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en), so then it counts as a single range:

`=COUNTIF({Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A1,Sheet3!A1,Sheet4!A1,Sheet5!A1}, "yes")`